# Where does the .gitignore file work?

Tags: git, github

What I mean by this is, is the `.gitignore` file in the repo that I am *pushing* doing the "ignoring" or is it the `.gitignore` file in the remote repo (e.g. Bitbucket) that does the ignoring?

So say I have 2 gitignore files: one in my local repo with `/static`

and one in my remote repo without `/static` ...

will the `static` directory from my local repo be pushed to the remote repo or will it be ignored? What exactly will be happening in the background processes?

Comment: `.gitignore` affects *what goes into the index* (aka staging-area). It has no effect on things that are *already* in the index. All files that are in the index (you can use `git ls-files --stage` to view the index contents, but this isn't really meant for human consumption) go into each new commit you make. When you run `git push` you push, not *files*, but *commits*, so what gets pushed depends on the commits you made. There are no files at all on Bitbucket; there are only commits there. You get those commits and from those commits, *you* extract files.

Answer (score 2):

The local `.gitignore` file in your repository does the ignoring when it comes to committing files in your local repository.

If you make changes to your `gitignore` file, these changes will show up in your local repositories state and you can then commit them and push them to a remote repository.

The fact that there is a remote repository somewhere, or even multiple remotes, does not affect the working of `gitignore` in your local repository.

The following commands show how a local repository, without a remote, uses .gitignore do determine which files are untracked:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/wouter/temp/.git/
touch .gitignore
vi .gitignore
cat .gitignore
*.txt
touch test.txt
touch test.json
git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore
        test.json

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

As you can see, the `test.txt` file is ignored by the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that the `.gitignore` file has no filter effect on tracked files (neither locally, nor in the remote).

The only purpose of the file is to hide you some untracked files that you don't want to commit when displaying the status and adding file to the staging area.